# Mocha with --watch flag set throws an error when using ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, watch

I've been trying to set up Mocha to automatically watch for changes in my files by using the --watch flag.
I've set up two scripts in package.json like so:

```
  "test": "mocha",
  "test:watch": "mocha --watch ./test ./game_logic"
```

When invoking the first script with `npm test` the tests are performed without an error, however when I invoke the second script with `npm run test:watch`, the following error is thrown:

```
 (node:149779) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load 
 ES Module: <path to test file contained in /test>
```

I don't quite understand the error message because I'm already using `import` whenever I'm importing whole files or separate functionalities from one file into another.

The documentation from Mocha states that writing test as ES modules is supported so I really don't have a clue why the described error occurs.

https://mochajs.org/#nodejs-native-esm-support

Answer (score 7):

As per [this issue](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/4374), a workaround is to add the `--parallel` flag, like so:

```
mocha --watch --parallel --recursive test
```

Comment: thx  <!-- Lorem Ipsum SO wants me to write more whatever I hate it. -->